# Prevent locking on custom Android app

Tags: android

What code would you use to prevent the Droid from locking on an app? I am writing an app that uses sockets, and it is essential that the screen not lock in the middle of the app's execution.

Answer (score 1):

Turn Off Screen Lock by adding the following against the Activity in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:keepScreenOn="true"
```

The screen will remain on and be cautious of using this as the display being kept on could impact your battery usage in you Application.

Comment: Is this for older versions of Android? I checked into it a bit and it does not seem to be valid on 2.2 in the manifest. However you can add this as an attribute  to any view in a standard layout.

Answer (score 0):

You need a wake lock, obtained from the [Power Manager.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean. But I took it to be an unresponsive UI. So if that assumption is correct threading is your answer, do your socket work in here so the UI does not "lock-up"

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){ 
        Code Here ....
    }
}).start();
```

Keep in mind also that if you have strange exceptions about modifying UI elements from this thread the Looper can sometimes be useful. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html

Comment: Actually what I meant was that the app goes to the locking screen after too long.

Comment: @Zach In that case I favor the suggestion by @Br810 I use it often in my Android layouts and it works great. If it works for you please make sure to accept his answer.